# SUM record with multiple join wrong

Tags: mysql

I have  3 table `request`, `plan`, `level`.

Here is table request:

```
 id  plan_id response_code client_id
  1  1        200           1          
  2  1        200           1
  3  1        400           1
  4  1        500           1
```

Here is table plan:

```
 id       client_id
  1             1         
  2             1
  3             1
  4             1
```

Here is table price:

```
     id  plan_id
      1  1               
      2  2       
      3  3       
      4  4
```

I want join 3 table and count in table request, how many record with response_code 200, 400, and 500. But I get wrong value. Here is my query

```
        SELECT 
      requests.id,
      SELECT SUM(case 
      when requests.response_code = 200 then 
      1 else 0
       end) as resquest200,
      SELECT SUM(case 
      when requests.response_code = 500 then 
      1 else 0
       end) as resquest500,
      response_code,
    FROM requests
    JOIN plan
    ON requests.plan_id = plan.id
    JOIN price
    ON plan.id = price.plan_id
    GROUP BY request.id
```

I tried:

```
 SELECT 
 request.id,
 (
SELECT SUM(case 
when request.response_code = 200 then 
1 else 0
end) FROM request) as resquest200,
response_code,
FROM request
JOIN plan
ON requests.plan_id = plan.id
JOIN price
ON plan.id = price.plan_id
GROUP BY request.id
```

and it sum correctly. How can I optimize my query? Please help me

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I expect: `response200: .., response400: .. ,response500: .., ...`

Comment: @Akashii as per your data representation and first query. There is no plan_id column in plan table and it is present in your query JOIN price ON plan.plan_id = price.plan_id

Comment: @RahulSingh sry, it's `plan.id = price.plan_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to establishing the total number of requests then `COUNT()` is a better option than `SUM()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*), response_code FROM requests
GROUP BY response_code
```

Why do you want to join onto plan and price? Is there some data that from these tables that you need to return?

Comment: I'm looking total number of each response_code request. example: `response200:10, response400: 20, response500: 30`

Comment: I don't think this needs any data from the plan or price tables? The request table seems to contain everything you need to return this level of information.

Comment: Yes I need data from two table but I not include this in example

Comment: Might be worth including an example of the data that you want to return. If you're grouping by response code then it's difficult to see how the data from the price and plan tables needs to be aggregated